# SUM value from last ID

Tags: php, sql, database, phpmyadmin

Can you help me with code in PHP for "SELECT"? I need to do SUM from database table with name "table1" from last ID. On the picture you can see values for SUM.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1` *without* aggregation:

```
SELECT (col1 + col2 + col3...)
FROM table1
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

This assumes that `id` is not duplicated in your table.  That seems like a reasonable assumption for a column called `id`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to make a `SUM` of all the columns.

There is no "trick" to do it automatically, you will have to list them:

```
SELECT SUM(col1 + col2 + col3...) as sum
FROM table1
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1; -- since you want only the last ID
```